# Mako templates using Django template tags

Tags: django, django-templates, mako, templatetags

Our Django site is built using Mako templates. We want to use a third party project called [django-socialregistration](http://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration), but its template tags use Django's templates. If we used Django templates we could just

```
{% load facebook_tags %}
{% facebook_button %}
{% facebook_js %}
```

How can I do the same thing in Mako? You can inline strait up python in Mako, but I haven't figured out how to do it that way either.

**Final Fix**

```
<%! from django.template import Template, Context %>
<% tpl = "{% load facebook_tags %}{% facebook_button %}{% facebook_js %}" %>
${Template(tpl).render(Context(dict_=dict(request=request)))}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've hardly used Mako, but if you can include arbitrary Python code, you could always inline the template rendering function there.

```
<%
    tpl = """{% load facebook_tags %}{% facebook_button %}{% facebook_js %}"""
    from django.template import Template, Context
    t = Template(tpl)
    t.render(Context())
%>
```

Comment: Hi, I posted a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799715/jinja2-templates-using-django-template-tags - thought I'd check to see if you have any advice.