# How to deal with Internationalization when using mako on django ,

Tags: python, django, internationalization, mako

this is code :

```
{% load i18n %}
{% trans 'hello test' %}
```

but , this code cant be read by `mako`,

so  how to Internationalization  using `mako` ,

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790854/mako-templates-using-django-template-tags looks similar, but I suppose it's only half the story since for trans you'd have to run a template block every time..

Answer (score 1):

I've checked the [documentation](http://www.makotemplates.org/docs/) and it describes that Mako uses [Babel](http://www.makotemplates.org/docs/usage.html#babel) for i18n. So you can either use that, or as @Yuji suggests, use Django's i18n by calling arbitrary Python code.

But I think using Babel is prettier:

```
# /myproj/babel.cfg

# this loads all Django templates, 
# e.g. /myproj/templates/myapp/hello_world.html
[mako: **/templates/**.*]

# /myproj/templates/myapp/hello_world.html
<html>
   <body>
       ${_('Hello world!')}
   </body>
</html>
```