# Jinja2 templates using Django template tags

Tags: templates, django-templates, jinja2

I'm using Jinja2 on a new project, but would like to use the [django-socialregistration](https://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration) app, which relies on Django template tags. Jinja2 doesn't play nicely with template tags, so I'm wondering if there's a quick workaround?

Template tags:
{% load facebook_tags %}
{% facebook_button %}
{% facebook_js %}

This [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790854/mako-templates-using-django-template-tags) addresses the same topic for Mako, but I'm having trouble adapting it to work with Jinja2. The following is my attempt at an adaptation (non-working):

```
{% from django.template import Template, Context %}
{% tpl = "{% load facebook_tags %}{% facebook_button %}{% facebook_js %}" %}
${Template(tpl).render(Context(dict_=dict(request=request)))}
```

Any advice? I'm new to inlining, so don't know if the above is even close.

Answer (score 1):

Should the last line not just be:

```
{% Template(tpl).render(Context(dict=dict(request=request))) %}
```