# using django filters in jinja2

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, jinja2, django-templates

I am developing an application on appengine, and want to use the awesome `timesince` django templatetag. Since I am using jinja2, I do not have the timesince filter available. How can I import it from django and use in jinja template.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799715/jinja2-templates-using-django-template-tags), but it does not serve the need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `timesince` function that the Django filter uses can be found here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/timesince.py

Documentation on writing custom jinja filters can be found here: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#custom-filters